# Method won't return an updated String

Tags: java, string, methods, return-value

I have a method that is supposed to get the input of a String from a user and validate 4 things:

that its only 1 word, doesn't contain spaces, doesn't contain numbers, and isn't blank/had the enter key pressed.

If any of these issues occur then an error msg is printed and the method is called again to re-prompt the user for input. If the string meets the requirements than the method returns the String.

In most cases the method works as intended, however, if I enter an incorrect repsonse the first time around then even after it prompts me with the error and I enter the correct response it returns the incorrect response I entered the first time. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

```
    public static String getName() {

    //Prompt User for Name and Store it as the tmp String
    System.out.print("Please enter the target string here: ");
    String tmp = in.nextLine();

    //Check to see if the string is blank, contains more than one word, or contains numbers. If so, give error and re-prompt
    if(tmp.equals("") || tmp.contains(" ") || tmp.contains("1") || tmp.contains("2") || tmp.contains("3") || tmp.contains("4")
    || tmp.contains("5") || tmp.contains("6") || tmp.contains("7") || tmp.contains("8") || tmp.contains("9") || tmp.contains("0")) {
        System.out.println("\nYou entered an invalid response, please try again\n");
        getName();
    }

    //Return the String
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must assign the string:

```
tmp = getName();
```

Comment: This. Would also suggest to @oznomal to look into regex for pattern matching.